# Connecting LED indicators

Tags: led, circuit-design

I have schematics of system that I design.

When SW1 is closed, SW2 is open and the battery getting charged via the `Charge Controller` with around 6 V and 500 mA.

When SW1 is open, SW2 is closed and the load gets current from the booster around 40 mA.

[image]

I would like to connect two LEDs as indicators, one for charging the battery and the other for the load.

Both LED's working current is 20 mA and voltage of 3 V, so connecting them in serial to the switches will damage them.

My question is how should I connect those LEDs indicators.

Thanks

Comment: The task is more complicated then you think. Connecting LED in series with some circuit you reduce the voltage of that circuit. Some current detector should be used, like Hall effect sensor for instance, with low resistance.

Comment: You are charging a 3.7V cell at 6V? That seems very unlikely.

Comment: Or smokey, hot and unhealthy.

Comment: This is easy if you can use double-pole switches.   i.e. https://www.electricaltechnology.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/DPST-Double-Pole-Single-Throw-Switch.png

Comment: @ElliotAlderson thanks for the comment, actually the CC vary the voltage according to the current voltage of the battery. I think the maximum voltage is 4.2v